# Image Convolution not working according to the actual algorithm

Tags: java, image-processing, convolution

I have implemented a convolution filter in java. I did this a while back in ap cs but now I actually need it for something, so I re implemented it to make sure I still know how to do it. Unfortunately I lost my working copy so I can't compare current code to my previous working code. I am pretty sure I am implementing the algorithm correctly, but the code is still not working properly. Can an experienced programmer please explain what I am doing wrong.

Here is the Convolution class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ConvolutionFilter {

    private int[][] image;
    private int[][] weights;
    private double[][] doubleWeights;

    private int[][] convolved;

    public ConvolutionFilter(int[][] image, int[][] weights) {

        this.image = image;
        this.weights = weights;

        convolve();
    }

    public void convolve() {

        int sum;
        int[][] convolved = new int[image.length][image[0].length];

        for (int r = 0; r < convolved.length - weights.length - 1; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < convolved[r].length - weights.length - 1; c++) {
                sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < weights[i].length; j++) {
                        sum += image[r + i][c + j] * weights[i][j];
                    }
                }
                convolved[r][c] = sum / weight();
            }
        }

        this.convolved = convolved;
    }

    public int numWeights() {
        return weights.length * weights[0].length;
    }

    public int weight() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < weights.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < weights[r].length; c++) {
                sum += weights[r][c];
            }
        }
        if (sum == 0) return 1; else return sum;
    }

    public int[][] getConvolved() {
        return convolved;
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "Does not work correctly". what sort of errors do you get/ do you have a stack trace?

Comment: The kernel is not "centered" on the output pixel, that's a little odd but maybe you meant to do that?

Comment: It is intentionally not centered. That should not matter though.

Comment: For example, when I use the blur kernel found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing) the result is that the image becomes only red, blue, black, and white

Comment: This convolution is invoked for every colour plane separately then, right? It's not a multi-channel convolution by itself

Comment: Im not sure I quite understand your question, but I'm guessing you are asking whether I convolve every color channel with this code. Currently I am not; the convolution happens on integer pixel values (not short). Does that clarify?

Comment: Then the implementation doesn't quite line up with the use, because this code treats its input and result as single-channel images. If you put packed RGB in there, then the channels get mixed up together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To adapt this to RGB, the arithmetic should be done per channel instead of over the packed representation, for example (not tested)

```
public void convolve() {
    int[][] convolved = new int[image.length][image[0].length];
    double invScale = 1.0 / weight();

    for (int r = 0; r < convolved.length - weights.length - 1; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < convolved[r].length - weights.length - 1; c++) {
            int rsum = 0, gsum = 0, bsum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < weights[i].length; j++) {
                    int pixel = image[r + i][c + j];
                    int w = weights[i][j];
                    rsum += ((pixel >> 16) & 0xFF) * w;
                    gsum += ((pixel >> 8) & 0xFF) * w;
                    bsum += (pixel & 0xFF) * w;
                }
            }
            rsum = (int)(rsum * invScale);
            gsum = (int)(gsum * invScale);
            bsum = (int)(bsum * invScale);
            convolved[r][c] = bsum | (gsum << 8) | (rsum << 16) | (0xFF << 24);
        }
    }

    this.convolved = convolved;
}
```